# Table return the result of two rows in one

Tags: sql, sql-server

if I have a table like this:

| MatchCode | TransferId |
| --- | --- |
| 17edce4d | 7 |
| 17edce4d | 17 |
| 20332cf0 | 22 |
| 20332cf0 | 30 |

is it possible make the result return this?

| MatchCode | TransferId1 | TransferId2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17edce4d | 7 | 17 |
| 20332cf0 | 22 | 30 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each `MatchCode` group will always have only two records, then you can use the `MIN` and `MAX` along with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MatchCode, MIN(TransferId) AS TransferId1, MAX(TransferId) AS TransferId2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY MatchCode
```